# Combobox inside datagrid raises selection change event multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Data Grid with `RowDetailsTemplate` which contains one inner data grid to show sub records and a user control to add new record (which contains one combo box and one button). Based on the combo box selection change I have to load some data from database and on button click I want to save that record into sub collection.

View

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="150"
                                                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                                Header="NAME" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Width="150"
                                                Binding="{Binding Email}"
                                                Header="EMAIL" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=Main.Organizations}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=Main.SelectedOrganization}"                                       
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},
                                                                                                  Path=Main.SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=Main.ButtonClickCommand}" Content="Click!" Height="50" Width="100"></Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

View Model

```
/// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ////if (IsInDesignMode)
            ////{
            ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Code runs "for real"
            ////}

            Employees = GetEmployees();

            Organizations = GetOrganizations();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Organization> GetOrganizations()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Organization>()
            {
                new Organization() {Id = 1, Name = "Org Name 1"},
                new Organization() {Id = 2, Name = "Org Name 2"},
                new Organization() {Id = 3, Name = "Org Name 3"},
                new Organization() {Id = 4, Name = "Org Name 4"},
                new Organization() {Id = 5, Name = "Org Name 5"}
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() {Id = 1, Email = "Email 1", Name = "Name 1"},
                new Employee() {Id = 2, Email = "Email 2", Name = "Name 2"},
                new Employee() {Id = 3, Email = "Email 3", Name = "Name 3"},
                new Employee() {Id = 4, Email = "Email 4", Name = "Name 4"},
                new Employee() {Id = 5, Email = "Email 5", Name = "Name 5"}
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get { return _employees; }

            set
            {
                _employees = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(()=>Employees);
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Organization> _organizations;
        public ObservableCollection<Organization> Organizations
        {
            get { return _organizations; }

            set
            {
                _organizations = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Organizations);
            }
        }

        private Organization _selectedOrganization;
        public Organization SelectedOrganization
        {
            get { return _selectedOrganization; }

            set
            {
                _selectedOrganization = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedOrganization);
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _selectionChangedCommand;
        public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectionChangedCommand ??
                       (_selectionChangedCommand =
                           new RelayCommand(() => OnSelectionChange()));
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand _buttonClickCommand;
        public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _buttonClickCommand ??
                       (_buttonClickCommand =
                           new RelayCommand(() => OnButtonClick()));
            }
        }

        private void OnButtonClick()
        {
            //button click event
        }

        private void OnSelectionChange()
        {
            //combobox selection change event
        }
    }
```

Lets come to the issue, for the first data grid row selection, everything works fine as expected. Select another row and select an item from the combo box will fire `SelectionChanged` event two times. The count will increase based on the data grid row selection. How can I handle this situation? Is this something related to routed events? I haven't registered any other events for combo box or data grid.

One workaround for this problem is by loading data on `SelectedOrganization` set method. But i have to make the database call asynchronous. So what is the best method to handle a scenarion like this?

Comment: The cause of your trouble is in the code that you are not showing, Whay stand for //combobox selection change event
? BTW, why do you want to handle the SelectionChanged for the Combobox and attach the command at the same time?

Comment: @E-Bat - Ouch.. Actually there is no event handler in the code behind. I have added that event for trouble shooting purpose. Forgot to remove during copy-paste..

Answer (score 0):

In the Setter of ButtonClickCommand property you are setting the variable  _selectionChangedCommand, instead of _buttonClickCommand:

```
public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _buttonClickCommand ??
            (_buttonClickCommand =
                new RelayCommand(() => OnButtonClick()));
            }
    set 
    { 
        _buttonClickCommand = value; 
    }
}
```

Also, I don't like the approach of initialize the command in the getter. I think you should move that initialization to the constructor of your ViewModel.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SelectionChangedCommand=
        new RelayCommand(() => OnSelectionChange()));
}

public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCommand {get;set;}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Relay command setter is not needed. edited post.

Comment: What are you doing in OnSelectionChange?

Comment: database call to display some related data in the detail template itself